# Deployment warning for JBoss 4.0.4 WARN [SchemaTypeCreator] JAX-RPC does not allow collection types skipping:

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jbossws

My web service can deploy and work fine with JBoss 5.0 but it gives above warning when try to deploy on JBoss 4.0.4 for following method

```
@WebMethod
        public AccountSummary getAccountSummaryForCustomer(String customerID)
        {

              //AccountSummary class has two ArrayLists as attributes
              return AccountSummary;
        }
```

I think sum libraries are missing in my server. How can I identify those libraries or solve this issue.?

This is the complete Warning on server terminal

WARN  [SchemaTypeCreator] JAX-RPC does not allow collection types skipping: com.directfn.webservices.AccountSummary.cashAccountDetails
WARN  [SchemaTypeCreator] JAX-RPC does not allow collection types skipping: com.directfn.webservices.AccountSummary.portfolioDetails

Comment: can you please post the warnings you are getting in your question. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your method’s return object AccountSummary may contain collection types that does not support the above jboss version. If your class contains any attributes as Object[] arrays, change them to specific object types.

Eg: change **Object[]** to **someClass[]**, hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Include all the **JBoss libraries** (jar files) to your project and check out. You can find those files in **JBoss client folder**.

Comment: I added all the lib files, but still same warning